# How to use two different databases in Migrations > Configuration - one for Web, one for Test?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

- I have a 3-tier MVC4 application - Web > Services > Core.
- I'm using EF Codefirst
- The data context and Migrations folder live in Core
- I'd like to re-use these but use a different database for my testing
- I've added another project called "Tests" to the solution - I'm trying to create another project that calls some of the services and uses a test database to validate that all CRUD operations are behaving as expected.
- I copied the `app.config` from Web over to the Tests project and removed all the web-specific stuff
- I specified a new database in the Test `app.config` here:

```
Catalog=Project.Services.Tests;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Project.Services.Tests.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

- I built the project successfully
- I added the following test class:

  ```
  [TestClass]
  public class ServiceTest
  {
      private TransactionScope _transactionScope;
      private SetServices _services;

      [TestInitialize]
      public virtual void TestInitialize()
      {
          _services = new SetServices();
          _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
      }

      [TestMethod]
      public void AddSet()
      {
          _services.CreateSet("New Set", "Details", null);
      }


      [TestCleanup]
      public void TestCleanup()
      {
          // rollback
          if (_transactionScope != null)
          {
              _transactionScope.Dispose();
          }
      }

  }
  ```

But when I run it I get:

> CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement
>   transaction.

Within my `CreateSet` method here:

```
 _db.Sets.Add(set);
```

I'm not sure why it's trying to CREATE a new database.  How can I begin to troubleshoot this?